# FFMPEG Seeking with concat demuxer causes video & audio to be out of sync

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a very simple use case that's driving me bananas.

My problem and question:

I'm using ffmpeg version 5.1.2 on a MacOS and i'm using ffmpeg seeking and concat demuxer to cut many 1 minute videos into 15 seconds chopped up over 12 clips where every clip is just 2 seconds from the same video (kind of like a mini teasers for the video). I would really like to not have to re-encode to make the video processing as fast as possible.

First, I take each 1 minute video and cut it up into 12 clips (I do all this programmatically in python fwiw)

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i input.mp4 -t 2 -c copy -y cut_1.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 4 -i input.mp4 -t 2 -c copy -y cut_2.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 8 -i input.mp4 -t 2 -c copy -y cut_3.mp4
...
...
```

I then write all the output file names to my `concat_manifest.txt`

```
file cut_1.mp4
file cut_2.mp4
...
...
```

Then I run my concat command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat_manifest.txt -c copy -y concat_video.mp4
```

This works really fast but the audio and video at the stitch point get out of sync and sometimes the video just chokes & lags. It's mostly not a smooth experience.

What I have tried:

1. using the concat protocol with intermediate profiles: [ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer)
2. Putting the -ss when I seek after the -i. This makes everything worse
3. Playing around with different -ss values. This has some noticeable affects but it's not obvious why yet.
4. I've also read from the ffmpeg resource regarding seeking and copying:

Which leads me to believe that maybe because ffmpeg is using timestamps instead of frames, seeking isn't accurate using -ss when using the concat demuxer

Is there a way to get concat demuxer cutting and concatenating the video where the audio is somewhat in sync with the video?

Thanks

EDIT: I found an answer and i'll be posting the solution in the coming few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to use concat demuxer without transcoding/re-encoding. The reason I avoided transcoding in the first place is because I couldn't figure out a way to cut & transcode ~15 seconds of video without it taking forever. The reason it took forever with transcoding was because I was using concat filters:

```
eg: 
[0]trim=0:2[v1];[0]trim10:2[v2]...;[v1][v2][v3]...concat=n=7:v=1[v]
```

That just ended up taking too long.

I ended up realizing I could just transcode/re-encode when seeking and then concat demuxer worked like a charm.

Step 1:
Trim with seek & re-encode at the same time. It's much faster.

```
ffmpeg -ss 5 -i input.mp4 -t 2 -vf "{scale_filter}" -y -avoid_negative_ts 1  {render_flags} cut1.mp4

ffmpeg -ss 10 -i input.mp4 -t 2 -vf "{scale_filter}" -y -avoid_negative_ts 1  {render_flags} cut2.mp4

ffmpeg -ss 20 -i input.mp4 -t 2 -vf "{scale_filter}" -y -avoid_negative_ts 1  {render_flags} cut3.mp4

etc...
```

Step 2:
Write all cuts to a segments.txt

```
file cut1.mp4
file cut2.mp4
etc...
```

Step 3:
Concat demux

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i segments.txt -c copy -fflags +genpts -avoid_negative_ts make_zero final.mp4
```